# How to set x ticks for seaborn (python) line plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I made a line plot chart for years 1960-2014 using seaborn but the xticks aren't correct. I want only intervals to appear (like 1960, 1970, 1980, etc).How do i adjust the xticks? I tried rotating it but it didn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
#plot figure using sns
g=sns.relplot(x="Year", y="Indicator_Value",
           data=Emissions_C_df,
           kind="line",
           style="Indicator_Name",
           hue="Indicator_Name",
           )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MaxNLocator` from `matplotlib.ticker` for the major ticks (decades) and manually set specific minor ticks with a `FixedLocator`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, MaxNLocator

a = np.arange(50)
d = {'Year': 1953+a, 'Indicator_Value': a}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

g = sns.relplot(x="Year", y="Indicator_Value",
           data=df,
           kind="line")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(steps=[10]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(range(1960,1970)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can i also add ticks in between? like 9 ticks between 1960-1970? I copied it to another line and tried changing it to "minor_locator" but it didn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer to include minor ticks.